# Can we run spark on mesos using the precompiled hadoop-spark package?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mesos

I have a Mesos Cluster on which I want to run Spark jobs.

I have downloaded the spark precompiled package and I can use the spark-shell by simply decompressing the archive.

So far, I haven't managed to run spark jobs on the Mesos Cluster.

**First question** : Do I need to install and build Spark from source to get it work on Mesos? And Does this precompiled package used only for Spark on Yarn and Hadoop?

**Second question** : Can anyone provide the best way to build spark. I have found many ways like :

- `sbt clean assembly`
- `./build/mvn -Pmesos -DskipTests clean package`
- `./build/sbt package`

I don't know which one to use, and whether they are all correct or not.

Comment: Use mvn, not sbt - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-mesos-support And did you try setting master to be Mesos with the pre-built one? What errors did you get?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I set the master to be mesos. The error is `initial job has not accepted any resources`, I have sufficient CPU, RAM and Disk on my Mesos slaves. Also I have disabled the dynamic resource allocation and other solutions I found related to this error. So it is very likely that the problem came from the installation itself, or some configurations like the `SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI` environment variable, which for the moment is set to the url for downloading the precompiled spark package

Comment: @AyoubOm could you please specify the spark-submit command in the ticket and its entire output. Are the resources in this Mesos cluster reserved for the role `*`?

Comment: Hi @AndreyDyatlov! In fact I didn't run `spark-submit`, only `spark-shell`. Could you please explain what you mean by the role `*`

Comment: @AyobOm. Debugging resource starvation in Mesos is not trivial. Usually, you need to access to Mesos and framework (in this case Spark) logs, configurations and some additional information, for example, the command with which you start your Spark job.

Comment: @AyobOm, I would recommend rephrasing your question specifying the command, you are running in the spark-shell and the output of this command. At the moment, the answer is trivial, but not very helpful: 1. No, 2. Use Maven.